# OOB Entity Not Showing in Site Map (Left Pane)

Tags: dynamics-crm, sitemap, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-uci, dynamics-365-sales

Have a client request to show OOB Contract entity under Sales area of Site Map (left nav pane).

I've added a new sub area under Sales area in site map and added the Contract entity as seen below.

[image]

[image]

However, after fussing with this for longer than anticipated, I still can't get the Contracts sub area to show under the Sales area as seen below:

[image]

What am I missing to get this to show?

Comment: able to figure this out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the issues should be around these points:

1. Make sure you are editing the correct UCI app sitemap using "Sitemap designer"
2. Add the assets/artifacts for that entity, ex. forms, views, security role privilege for that UCI app security role in "App designer"
3. Is there any privilege check added to subarea settings?
4. Please publish all customizations
5. Clear cache or try incognito browser
6. Sometimes the issue surfaced when entity was not enabled for mobile or marked as read-only in entity settings page. Check this too

[image]

[Read more](https://us.hitachi-solutions.com/blog/dynamics-365-roadmap-edit-dynamics-365-apps-app-designer-sitemap-designer/)

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response.  So I was able to display a custom entity in left pane under sales, but not the OOB 'Contracts' entity.  Per your suggestion, I looked at the entity 'Contract' entity settings in my solution and the "enable for unified client" option is grayed out therefore not letting me select it. I am quite confident this might be the issues. Any work around for this?

Comment: @Squ1rr3lz, yes unfortunately contract is deprecated, entitlement is the replacement entity. Refer this [community thread](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/microsoft-dynamics-crm-forum/380078/contracts-in-crm-unified-interface) and [MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customerengagement/on-premises/developer/contract-entities)

Comment: Oh that's right. In fact I let my client know that a couple weeks ago and completely forgot *face palm*